# expect parameter @FDate, which was not supplied, though i am passing the parameter :s

Tags: sql, database, procedure

```
USE [SDE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[RPT_GET_STAFF_CALL_DATA]
@FDate datetime, @FTDate datetime
as
SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @FDTE datetime, @TDTE datetime
/*Set @FDTE = convert(datetime,@FDate,101)
Set @TDTE =  convert(datetime,@FTDate,101)
*/
Set @FDTE= @FDate
Set @TDTE = @FTDate


Select  
"SEQUENCE", 
"FNAME", 
"NAME", 
    ("FNAME" + ' ' + "NAME") as 
"Full Name",
    (SELECT count("SEQUENCE") 
    FROM "_SMDBA_"."_TELMASTE_" as INC 
    WHERE INC."SENT TO" = "_SMDBA_"."_PERSONNEL_"."SEQUENCE"
        and "DATE OPEN" >= @FDTE 
        and "DATE OPEN" < @TDTE) as 
"Assigned Calls", 
    (SELECT count("SEQUENCE")
    FROM "_SMDBA_"."_TELMASTE_" as INC 
    WHERE INC."SENT TO" = "_SMDBA_"."_PERSONNEL_"."SEQUENCE"
        and datediff(year,"DATE OPEN",getdate()) = 0) as 
"Opened Calls YTD",
    (SELECT count("SEQUENCE") 
    FROM "_SMDBA_"."_WORKORD_" as WO 
    WHERE WO."OPEN BY" = "_SMDBA_"."_PERSONNEL_"."SEQUENCE" 
        and "DATE OPEN" >= @FDTE 
        and "DATE OPEN" < @TDTE) as 
"Opened WO's",
    (SELECT count("SEQUENCE") 
    FROM "_SMDBA_"."_WORKORD_" as WO 
    WHERE WO."OPEN BY" = "_SMDBA_"."_PERSONNEL_"."SEQUENCE" 
        and datediff(year,"DATE OPEN",getdate()) = 0) as 
"Opened WOS YTD",
    (SELECT count("SEQUENCE") 
    FROM "_SMDBA_"."_TELMASTE_" as INC 
    WHERE INC."SOLVED_BY" = "_SMDBA_"."_PERSONNEL_"."SEQUENCE"
        and "HD_CCDT01" >= @FDTE 
        and "DATE OPEN" < @TDTE) as 
"Closed Calls",
    (SELECT count("SEQUENCE") 
    FROM "_SMDBA_"."_TELMASTE_" as INC 
    WHERE INC."SOLVED_BY" = "_SMDBA_"."_PERSONNEL_"."SEQUENCE"
        and datediff(year,"DATE OPEN",getdate()) = 0) as 
"Closed Calls YTD",
(SELECT count("SEQUENCE") FROM "_SMDBA_"."_WORKORD_" as WO 

    WHERE WO."CLOSED BY" = "_SMDBA_"."_PERSONNEL_"."SEQUENCE" 
    and "CLOSED ON" >= @FDTE and "DATE OPEN" < @TDTE) 
    as "Closed WO's",
(SELECT count("SEQUENCE") FROM "_SMDBA_"."_WORKORD_" as WO 
    WHERE WO."CLOSED BY" = "_SMDBA_"."_PERSONNEL_"."SEQUENCE" 
    and datediff(year,"CLOSED ON",getdate()) = 0)  
    as "Closed WOS YTD",
(SELECT count("SEQUENCE") FROM "_SMDBA_"."_TELMASTE_" WHERE 
    "DATE OPEN" >= @FDTE and "DATE OPEN" < @TDTE) 
    as TOT_Calls_DRNGE,
(SELECT count("SEQUENCE") FROM "_SMDBA_"."_TELMASTE_" WHERE datediff(year,"DATE OPEN",getdate()) = 0) 
    as TOT_Calls_YTD,
(SELECT count("SEQUENCE") FROM "_SMDBA_"."_WORKORD_" WHERE
    "DATE OPEN" >= @FDTE and "DATE OPEN" < @TDTE) 
    as TOT_WOS_DRNGE,
(SELECT count("SEQUENCE") FROM "_SMDBA_"."_WORKORD_" WHERE datediff(year,"DATE OPEN",getdate()) = 0) 
    as TOT_WOS_YTD,
@FDTE as "From Date",@TDTE as "To Date"

FROM "_SMDBA_"."_PERSONNEL_"

order by "Full Name"
```

Procedure or function ' ' expects parameter '@FDate', which was not supplied.
The error displays for the @FDate and @FTDate ?!! can anyone help me

Am using this procedure in a crystal report and whenever i set the database location for the report it asks for the parameters and i provide them, but with no luck i then get the error ?!!

Comment: Are you sure you're providing the correct parameter name (including correct parameterisation) when you call the procedure?